# How to get rid of the stocks app from spotlight?

Tags: spotlight

I run OS running on german - there the stocks app ("Aktien") clashes with the activity monitor ("Aktivitätsanzeite").

I prefer to launch apps via spotlight.  Often just a millisecond before I press enter a new suggestion jumps to the top of the list and is launched instead.

Suppose something uses up all CPU and I want to investigate by activity monitor (german: Aktivitätsanzeite). I start typing "Akti" - see the correct App (top suggestion) and hit enter - but (half the time?) "Aktien" (the stocks app) pops up and jumps the top of the list - and I end up in the setup for the stocks app.  Very annoying if something else already grinds your system down.

I have a similar issue with other apps - but not as annoying as I can just delete the unwanted ones
I experimented using the "original" name - but it is a guessing game as the only way to figure the name out is to guess the name (it's nowhere mentioned in the apps).

Comment: You can always type the English name (**act**ivity monitor, no interference with **Akt**ien) and launch the app like that

Comment: Spotlight should 'learn' your preferred choice, so make sure you choose the correct one a few times, and then it should always be first. Obvs, if you accidentally choose the wrong one, then that will affect the order next time.

Comment: @benwiggy the point is *should*. For some reason it pops up top. Maybe the problem is if I mistype e.g. "Aktii" (happens when the system lags so much that letters don't appear) is *always* corrected to Aktien.

Comment: @X_841 - as I mention it's a workaround, not using it as much as it takes longer to complete (think several ten seconds instead of instant).

Comment: @bdecaf true, if it takes you too long to think about it, I see your point. For me though, this is fast enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want an app showing in **Spotlight** you can add it to the **Privacy** *tab* in: **System Preferences** > **Spotlight** > **Privacy**

You can add by clicking **[+]**, or drag a folder, disk or app into the list section.

Comment: I was to complain that the app is not selectable in the + dialogue. Turns out drag and drop seems to work. What horrible ux!